flutterでラジオボタンを横並びにしたい
flutterでwebアプリのUIを作っています。
ラジオボタンやチェックボックスを横並びにしたいのですが、ネット上の下記のようなコードを参考にしていますが、ラジオボタンやチェックボックスを増やし、ウィンドウサイズを小さくしていくとはみ出してしまいますが良い解決方法を導き出せていません。
画面サイズを小さくすることで、ラジオボタンやチェックボックスのテキストを折り返し表示するか、ウィンドウサイズが大きく時は横並びに、小さくしていくと画面サイズに合わせてチェックボックスごと折り返し表示したいと考えています。
flutterに知見のある方、ご教授お願い致します。
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
  children: [
    Row(
      children: [
        Radio(
          value: 0,
          groupValue: 0,
          onChanged: (value) {},
        ),
        Text('アイテム１')
      ],
    ),
    Row(
      children: [
        Radio(
          value: 1,
          groupValue: 0,
          onChanged: (value) {},
        ),
        Text('アイテム２')
      ],
    ),
    Row(
      children: [
        Radio(
          value: 2,
          groupValue: 0,
          onChanged: (value) {},
        ),
        Text('アイテム３')
      ],
    ),
  ],
),


teratail で解決済みのようです。
